# When do if constructs not require brackets?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, grep, brackets

I'm doing some homework for a shell scripting class and had a question asking me to write a script that tests whether or not the argument entered is a valid shell variable name. The below script seems to work fine.

```
if echo "$1" | grep -v ".*[^A-Za-z_]" > /dev/null
then
        echo yes
else
        echo no
fi
```

I understand brackets are short hand for the test function in the BASH shell. My problem is that, when I attempted the above script using brackets I got an error.

```
if [ echo "$1" | grep -v ".*[^A-Za-z_]" > /dev/null ]
```

The problem with this (I believe) is that grep is trying to use the ] as its argument, thus resulting in an error when the script is run.

In what situations do I not need brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[`/`test` is a command (also a built-in), as you said. It is a command that accepts arguments of a specific sort and behaves in a specific way given those arguments.

It accepts flags and comparison operators and operates on those to obtain a `true` or `false` result. It then translates that result into a return code. `0` for `true` and `1` for `false`.

The `if` construct in the shell is defined

> if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
>
> The if list is executed. If its exit status is zero, the then list is executed. Otherwise, each elif list is executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding then list is executed and the command completes. Otherwise, the else list is executed, if present. The exit status is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition tested true.

So when `[`/`test` returns an exit code that is what `if` evaluates.

The reason you don't need (and can't use) `[` around the `echo` command/pipeline is because that isn't a valid set of `[` arguments. Instead that is a command `list` itself and, as such, does not need to be evaluated by `[`. You can simply use it directly and have the return code of the pipeline handed to `if` for evalution.

Comment: Thanks for responding, the last bit especially cleared up my confusion. I didn't realize commands had return codes.

Comment: @xcerule The return code of the *most recent command* is stored in `$?`. The "most recent" bit is important since it affects things like 'some_complex_command; echo "status message"; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ... fi` which a lot of people try by accident without realizing they've just clobbered the return code of their complex command with the return code of `echo`. Additionally, the return code of a pipeline is the return code of the last command in the pipeline (no matter what any other command returns, but see `pipefail` and the `$PIPESTATUS` variable in the bash man page for more).

Answer (score 4):

`[` is actually a command (it happens to be built into most shells), not just part of the syntax of an `if` statement.

The `if` statement executes the command that is its argument. If that command *succeeds* (sets `$?` to zero), then the condition is true; if it *fails* (sets `$?` to some non-zero value), the condition is false.

The built-in `[` command is almost exactly equivalent to the `test` command; the difference is that `[` requires `]` as its last argument.

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22728/10454

Answer (score 1):

You may also use double square brackets `[[` instead of single `[`

Read more about it here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031:

```
[ ("test" command) and [[ ("new test" command) are used to
evaluate expressions. [[ works only in Bash, Zsh and the Korn shell,
and is more powerful; [ and test are available in POSIX shells
```

Comment: Uhms the format is a bit lost when quoting, it is difficult to know what is the best way to format.