# See if a service is running with exit code

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, grep

I Have made a simple script which checks if the service is running and returning a exit code, but I cant make it work. Exit 0 if it works, and 1 if it doesn't.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Plugin for checking if the SSH service is running

SERVICE='ssh'

if [ ps aux | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null ];
then
        exit 0
else
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do if constructs not require brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725431/when-do-if-constructs-not-require-brackets)

Comment: Look at [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html)

Comment: I removed the bracket, it worked. But when I excecute it it only returns 0 if the service ssh is not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement can be replaced with simply

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -q "$SERVICE"
```

The exit status of the pipeline is 0 if `grep -q` succeeds (i.e., matches `ssh`), and 1 otherwise. If this is the last line of the script, the exit status of the shell will be the same: no need for an explicit call to `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the cause of the problem:

```
if [ ps aux | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null ];
```

- The syntax of an if statement: `if list; then ...` ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs))
- `if` chooses which branch to execute based on the exit status of the list
- A `list` is basically a pipeline of commands ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists))
- You are using the `[` command -- yes, it's a command not just syntax. The `[` command has specific requirements for the arguments it accepts ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions))
- `[` does not like the arguments you gave it.

You want to do this

```
if ps aux | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null; then
```

or, better, take chepner's advice and accept his answer.